# Are arithmetic equations implicitly evaluated in NULLIF()

Tags: sql, oracle, nullif

My SQL Fundamentals 1 Exam Guide states,

> ```
> select NULLIF(1234, 123+1) from dual;
> ```
>
> The arithmetic equation is not implicitly evaluated...

However, when I submit the query below the result is `null` - it seems that 123+1 **is** evaluated (although I know that the queries are different).

```
select NULLIF(124, 123+1) from dual;
```

So, which is correct (for the 1Z0-051 Exam, anyway)? Are expressions evaluated or not?

Comment: Your query does **not** return `null` for me, but `1234` (the first expression as stated at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions102.htm when the expressions are not equal) - which version of oracle are you using? See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e61514/3

Comment: I tried it in SQLFiddle for 11gR2, and it returns null for me

Comment: @Incognito Can you post the link to your SQLFiddle?

Comment: @Andreas I think you have used the query which OP has posted, which has an error. He has used 123+1, instead of 1233+1 :) Check this SQLFiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/23313

Comment: @Incognito Thats true, with `1233+1` I also get null

Comment: Please [don't alter code in questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101583/when-is-it-appropriate-to-edit-someone-elses-code?rq=1) @Yaroslav. Ask the poster if it's incorrect and request that they change it. It's often the reason for the problem in the first place. However, in this case  the OP seems well aware that 123+1 is not equal to 1234, _"although I know that the queries are different"_. In changing the code you also invalidated Nicholas' answer, which makes the entire Q&A a little pointless.

Comment: @Ben My apologies. Have thought of that when it was too late. Thank you for correcting it back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Nullif()` function evaluates both arguments and returns `NULL` if `argument1` equal to `argument2`. In your case `123+1` is not equal to `1234`. `123+1` is equal to `124` not `1234`.

> the result is null

It cannot be `null` in your case.

```
SQL> select nullif(1234, 123+1) as res
   2    from dual;

       RES
----------
      1234



SQL> select nullif(1234, 1233+1) as res
  2    from dual
  3  ;

       RES
----------
 NULL
```

**FOLLOW UP:** My 2 cents

The above `NULLIF` is equivalent to the below case

```
CASE WHEN 1234=123+1 THEN NULL ELSE 1234 END
```

You cannot specify the literal `NULL` for the first expression.

Also from [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions102.htm)

> If both arguments are numeric datatypes, then Oracle Database
>   determines the argument with the higher numeric precedence, implicitly
>   converts the other argument to that datatype, and returns that
>   datatype. If the arguments are not numeric, then they must be of the
>   same datatype, or Oracle returns an error.

Comment: Another SO downvote mistery... Got a bunch of those myself. Seems to get more common these days.

Comment: @Nicholas Krasnov: So, the answer is that the expression `123+1`**is** evaluated, correct? Thanks again.